# Check the number in form: odd, even, odd, even

Tags: php, validation, numbers

I have to write the function to check validation of input number from browser:

-> is numeric
-> has 6 letters
-> in form: odd+even+odd+even,... the 1st character can be odd or even.

For example: 123456 => true; 234567 => true

I wrote:

```
function check_code($code){
    if (!is_numeric($code)) return false;
    if (strlen($code)<>6) return false;
    $c = str_split($code);
    if (($c[0]+$c[1])%2==1 && ($c[1]+$c[2])%2==1 && ($c[2]+$c[3])%2==1 && ($c[3]+$c[4])%2==1 && ($c[4]+$c[5])%2==1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there any other solution "shorter and smarter" than above code? Thank you

Comment: Can you post what you expect as well

Comment: I said what I expect, a solution shorter and smarter than I wrote

Comment: I mean this **the 1st number can be odd or even**

Comment: It mean, the 1st character in string, can be odd or even. In the above example, the 1st from 123456 is 1. The 1st from 234567 is 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider rewriting the logic using the modulus operator into a for loop:

```
function check_code($code)
{
    if (!is_numeric($code)) return false;
    if (strlen($code)<>6) return false;
    $c = str_split($code);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); $i++) {
        if (isset($c[$i + 1])) {
            if (($c[$i] + $c[$i + 1]) % 2 !== 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```